# Trying to float two background images side by side, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: css, html, containers

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="final.css">
</head>

<body>
    <section id="container">

    <div id="sec1">
    </div>

    <div id="sec2">
    </div>

    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    margin-right: 10em;
    margin-left: 10em;
    border:1px dotted black;
    height: 62em;
}

#sec1{
    background: url('11.png') no-repeat left fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    min-height: 62em;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}

#sec2{
    background: url('33.png') no-repeat right fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I have my first background image in the correct left-side position (11.png), but the second background image isn't visible at all and I can't figure out where I went wrong. I'm still a newbie, so I don't know how to use grids yet - so I'm going to wrap everything inside of containers.

[image]

Comment: Do you really want a fixed size? Otherwise you could use float: left for both div's.

Comment: I decided to do a fixed size because I plan on making it responsive and it'll be easier to resize everything (?) I don't understand why I can't float as it is. Both containers are exactly the same except for the 'right' and 'left', but only the left is visible  and in position.

Comment: @Calisto close your qoute `<meta charset="utf-8>` Need to know what `final.css` has.

Comment: final is the css I displayed

Answer (score 1):

The second div doesn't have a height. Floats will work fine to arrange them, but give them the desired heights and widths so they have visible dimensions.

```
#sec1{
    background: url('11.png') no-repeat left fixed;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    min-height: 62em;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

#sec2{
    background: url('33.png') no-repeat right fixed;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    min-height: 20em;
    float: right;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! This works. Although when I scroll down a white rectangle hovers over the top of sec1 (only sec1). Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Float the divs

```
#sec1{
    background: url('11.png') no-repeat left fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    min-height: 62em;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:50%
}

#sec2{
    background: url('33.png') no-repeat right fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: auto;
    -moz-background-size: auto;
    -o-background-size: auto;
    background-size: auto;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    float:right;
    width:50%;

}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried replacing my sections with yours but I'm getting the same results.

Also, I tried it my way but this time put sec2 div inside sec1 it worked..I don't know why, but it messy and I dont like it.